# Why isn't this C program for calculating the area of a triangle working for all inputs?

Tags: c, debugging, turbo-c++

The following is the source code of a program which calculates the area of a triangle when the sides are given.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>

void main()
{
int a,b,c;
float s,area;
clrscr();
printf("Enter the lengths of the sides of the triangle:\n");
scanf("%d%d%d",&a,&b,&c);
s=(a+b+c)/2;
area=sqrt(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c));
printf("Area=%f",area);
getch();
}
```

I used the Turbo C++ compiler Version 3.0 to compile the program. When I give the sides as 10, 10 and 10, I get the area as 43.301270 which is correct. But when I plug the values as 1,1 and 1, the program gives the area as 0.000000 which is obviously wrong. Further, when I plug in the values as 3,3 and 3 I get the area as 2.000000 which is wrong.

Does anyone know the reason for the program's erratic behavior? How can it be corrected? I have [uploaded the program as a Zip file](https://sites.google.com/site/mydloadport/marketing-docs/TRIANGLE.zip?attredirects=0&d=1).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: Step through the code in the debugger and inspect the variable values after each line. Look for the first one that has the wrong value. That will point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using integer arithmetic for the calculation of `s` and suffering from truncation. Change your program like this to use floating point arithmetic.

```
s=(a+b+c)/2f;
```

Answer (score 3):

Given that each of `a`, `b`, and `c` is an `int`; then `a+b+c` is an `int`.
`2` is also an `int`.

`(a + b + c) / 2` is integer division.

Try `(a + b + c) / 2.0`.

And prefer to use `double`s for floating point values.

Answer (score 1):

```
s=((float)a+b+c)/2.0f;
```